# OneToOne, OneToMany or ManyToOne relationship for column referencing the same table

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, typeorm

I want to design a *Path* entity. This entity has an ID column which is not autogenerated. The *Path* entity might have a successor. That foreign key is nullable but when assigning an ID that does not exist I want to throw an error. So I started with this

```
@Entity()
export class Path extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn() // I will set this manually
  public id: string;

  @OneToMany(() => Path, path => path.id, { nullable: true }) // relation setup
  public successorId?: string;
}
```

But I am not sure if I have to use a *OneToOne*, *OneToMany* or *ManyToOne* column. So

- one path can have only one successor
- one path can be the successor of many paths

So I think my entity design seems to be correct but I am not sure. What is the correct decorator to use here in terms of databse design? Would be awesome if someone could help :) Btw. I'm supporting Postgres and MSSQL right now.

Comment: A nullable FK is perfectly valid, and it will throw an error is assigned a value that is not in the referenced table.  This works for 1:1, 1:M, and M:M.

Comment: thanks for your reply but which one is the correct decorator to use =? (in terms of database design)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "decorator to use". You seem to know how to create a FK. Once created everything flows automatically within the database. Nothing further for you to do.  You use the column(s) the FK is based on the same as if it were not there. If you are linking tables it is simply  ***FK column name(s) = Reverences column name(s)***.

Comment: sorry, this was a TypeORM/Typescript related question. I don't know if this is a `OneToMany` relationship or `OneToOne`. I don't think it's `ManyToOne`